# Open .gdb files using Python Script or By ogr2ogr

Tags: python, file-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase

I have data which basically looks like this.
[image: Image of data]

How can I extract that into csv or text format? So that I can dump that into a certain database.
Tried a lot of times but always get the error like this - "Unable to open datasource" with following error:
Python script or Ogr2Ogr command helps a lot.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest following next steps in QGIS:

> Processing > Toolbox > GDAL/OGR > gdal2xyz (ability to save as .csv)

[image: gdal-gdbtable]

Otherwise, you can try to use ESRI ArcGIS, it was partially described at [Opening *.gdb folder in ArcMap?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64182)

Comment: Thanks, Taras for your answer. But can you please help with ogr2ogr command since usage of the tool is not recommended in the task. Appreciate your help.

Comment: I think I can refer you to [this article](https://gis.ucla.edu/node/53).